# What should the dc_suffix in the cassandra-rackdc.properties be set to when using GoogleCloudSnitch in multi datacenter cluster?

Tags: cassandra

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archSnitchGoogle.html?hl=googlecloudsnitch

According these docs for Cassandra when using multiple datacenters the cassandra-rackdc.properties for each node should have its dc_suffix set. However it is not very specific if the suffix can be arbitrary or should relate to something. can someone please elaborate further on this?

Our case is that we will setup a nine node cluster and use GoogleCloudSnitch. For this question we can assume we will have our cluster as specified below:

- Region: europe-west1, Zone: b, c, d (one node on each zone)
- Region: europe-west2, Zone: a, b, c (one node on each zone)
- Region: europe-west3, Zone: a, b, c (one node on each zone)

The keyspaces will use NetworkTopologyStrategy with replication 3 on all datacenters.

The docs in the link above states the datacenter name is case-sensitive so I assume it should be e.g. "dc_suffix=b" for the b-zone node in europe-west1 and so forth even though the examples in docs shows arbitrary names. Just want it to be confirmed so I think correctly on this, what is the right dc_suffix?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR;**

> You don't have to explicitly setup rackdc.properties file if you are using
>   "GoogleCloudSnitch". Rather you only need this for
>   "GossipingPropertyFileSnitch".

Your understanding is correct that within rackdc.properties file, the value for both "dc" and "Rack" can be arbitrary. But its important to realize that the "dc" value for each node of a cluster dictates which datacenter they belong to. Similarly "Rack" represents within that "dc" which rack the machine is located.

So in your case "dc" would be "europe-west1" / "europe-west2" / "europe-west3" to configure 3 DataCenters. And "Rack" value would be "a" / "b" / "c" / "d" respectively. Configuring the rackdc.porperties file this way would make your "nodetool status" output look like

```
    Datacenter: europe-west1
    =======================
    Status=Up/Down
    |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
    --  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
    UN  127.0.0.1  47.66 KB   1       33.3%   aaa1b7c1-6049-4a08-ad3e-3697a0e30e10  b
    UN  127.0.0.2  47.67 KB   1       33.3%   1848c369-4306-4874-afdf-5c1e95b8732e  c
    UN  127.0.0.3  47.67 KB   1       33.3%   49578bf1-728f-438d-b1c1-d8dd644b6f7f  d

    Datacenter: europe-west2
    =======================
    Status=Up/Down
    |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
    --  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
    UN  127.0.0.4  47.66 KB   1       33.3%   aaa1b7c1-6049-4a08-ad3e-3697a0e30e10  a
    UN  127.0.0.5  47.67 KB   1       33.3%   1848c369-4306-4874-afdf-5c1e95b8732e  b
    UN  127.0.0.6  47.67 KB   1       33.3%   49578bf1-728f-438d-b1c1-d8dd644b6f7f  c

    Datacenter: europe-west3
    =======================
    Status=Up/Down
    |/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
    --  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns    Host ID                               Rack
    UN  127.0.0.1  47.66 KB   1       33.3%   aaa1b7c1-6049-4a08-ad3e-3697a0e30e10  a
    UN  127.0.0.2  47.67 KB   1       33.3%   1848c369-4306-4874-afdf-5c1e95b8732e  b
    UN  127.0.0.3  47.67 KB   1       33.3%   49578bf1-728f-438d-b1c1-d8dd644b6f7f  c
```

But this configuration of rackdc.properties file is required if you are using "GossipingPropertyFileSnitch".

With "GoogleCloudSnitch" you don't have to configure this file explicitly, still get the benefits of Rack and DC information for free. As this snitch tells Cassandra to infer the DC and Rack value automatically.

Comment: Just want one more thing to be straighten out since I realized your answer only applies when using a single datacenter on Google. What would dc_suffix be in this the scenario with multiple datacenters that the examples shows?  The documentation states that dc_suffix should be set but could this be arbitrary or should it map to something specific? Note that it is "dc_suffix" I am asking for not "dc" or" rack".

Comment: Its essentially a "suffix" value that gets appended to the "DC" value that you specify. In case of using GoogleCloudSnitch OR AWSSnitch default DC name would the region (for example us-east in AWS). Within us-east if you want to create two logical DC's say analytics and OLTP, you can spin up certain nodes with dc_suffix = "-analytics" and others with "-OLTP". It just gets appended to DC "us-east" to become us-east-analytics.